# Prove, that $p\in\mathbb{R}[x]$ with $p=x^2+ax+b$ is irreducible if and only if $a^2<4b$.

Tags: polynomials, ring-theory, irreducible-polynomials

> Prove, that $p\in\mathbb{R}[x]$ with $p=x^2+ax+b$ is irreducible if
>   and only if $a^2<4b$.

$"\leftarrow"$ Let $a^2<4b \iff b>\frac{a^2} 4$

\begin{align}
&x^2+ax+b=0\\
x_{1/2}=&\frac a 2\pm \underbrace{\sqrt{\frac{a^2}{4}-b}}_{\text{is negative: } b>\frac{a^2} 4}
\end{align}
$\implies$ We have no roots! Therefore, the polynomial is irreducible

$"\rightarrow"$  Assume, $p$ is irreducible, $\nexists q,z\in\mathbb{R}[x]:p=q\cdot z$. How to go on now?

Comment: In the title, you seem to have a typo (K instead of R)

Comment: If the discriminant is non-negative, we have at least one real root $r$ , hence the polynomial is reducible ($x-r$ is a factor)

Comment: @Peter thanks, I've fixed it!

Comment: At the bottom of the question, it should be R as well , right ?

Comment: Yeah, sorry ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $\rightarrow$ you can prove the counterpositive. Assume that $a^2\geq 4b$ and conclude from that that $p$ factors.

The same quadratic formula gives you that the factorization works over the reals, since this time the radicand is non-negative.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Do you mean *contrapositive* (as opposed to counterpositive)?

Answer (score 2):

For a clean proof, you can do the following: observe that $x^2+ax+b$ is reducible exactly when it can be written into the product of linear factors $(x-\alpha_1)(x-\alpha_2)$, which is true exactly when  it has two real roots. This is true exactly when the discriminant is strictly positive. This does both directions at once!

Caveat: We do need to know the fact that we can write $x^2+ax+b=(x-\alpha_1)(x-\alpha_2)$ exactly when it has two real roots. The forward direction is trivial, but the other direction requires slightly more thought. It follows from the fact that $\mathbb R[x]$ is a [Euclidean domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_domain), as it allows us to use the Remainder Theorem (equivalently, polynomial division).